# does not name a type error c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

I have segregated the code in two files as shown below. Here is the header file `graph.h`

```
//graph.h
#ifdef GRAPH_H
#define GRAPH_H

#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

#include "kernel_def.h"

using namespace std;

typedef vector<bool> Array;
typedef vector<Array> TwoDArray;

class baseGraph {
    private:
        int nodes;  /*Number of nodes.*/
        vector<feature_vector *> vec;   /*vector of feature nector.*/
    public:
        baseGraph(int nodes);
        /*set-get functions*/
        int getNodes();
        void setNodes(int nodes);
        const feature_vector *getVec(int pos);
        int setVec(int pos, feature_vector *fVec);

        /*Input edges from file and set up in corresponding representation.*/
        virtual void setGraph(ifstream &ipf) = 0;

        /*Utility functions*/
        virtual void printGraph() = 0;
        virtual feature_vector *subgraph_d(int node, int depth) = 0;    /*subgraph upto depth d.*/
};
```

Here is `graph.cpp`

```
//graph.cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "graph.h"

using namespace std;

baseGraph::baseGraph(int nodes) {
    setNodes(nodes);
    /*feature vetors will be assigned later.*/
    vec.resize(nodes);
    for(int i=0;i<nodes; ++i)
        vec.at(i) = NULL;
}
```

While compiling I get error that `src/graph.cpp:7:1: error: ‘baseGraph’ does not name a type`. I do not understand why this is happening. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Take another look at your include guards in graph.h.

Comment: Yup. Got that. This thing was getting me frustrated.

Comment: Use `#pragma once` instead of guards, then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First line of the source.

```
#ifdef GRAPH_H
```

should be

```
#ifndef GRAPH_H
```